# Sum of same days of complex Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, sum

The question has a base on the following SO:

[Groupy brings only one key from Pandas dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055711/groupy-brings-only-one-key-from-pandas-dictionary/64068657#64068657)

Dataframe looks like:

```
ALUP11  Return %    Day CESP6   Return %    Day TAEE11  Return %    Day
Data                                    
2020-08-13  23.81   0.548986    13.0    29.38   -2.747435   13.0    28.33   -0.770578   13.0
2020-09-01  23.68   1.067008    1.0     30.21   0.365449    1.0     28.55   1.205246    1.0
2020-08-31  23.43   -1.139241   31.0    30.10   -2.336145   31.0    28.21   -0.669014   31.0
2020-08-28  23.70   1.455479    28.0    30.82   1.615562    28.0    28.40   0.459851    28.0
2020-08-27  23.36   -0.680272   27.0    30.33   -1.717434   27.0    28.27   0.354988    27.0
```

After having the dataframe from dictionary, I need the sum of same days but

```
result = df.groupby('Day').agg({'Return %': ['sum']})
result
```

Get error:

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'Day' not 1-dimensional
```

For each symbol I would like to sum same days of month. In the example I have 3 symbols, so the result should be like:

[image]

Comment: Do you hava a MultiIndex ?

Comment: I do not think it is multiindex...it is only that for each symbol I have 3 columns of different data (close, Return% and Day). I would like to perfiorm operation of sum with column Return % for same days, so it will ahve to jump over some columns in order to get the result.

Comment: `assert not isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex)` return a error?

Comment: I guess this is out of my league

Comment: What happend if you run code above?

Comment: No error just running as it is (using my dataframe name instead of 'df')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222093/discussion-between-daniel-bittencourt-and-ansev).

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like the data in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64068657/13876078), the error is because you have two columns named `Day`. As they appear to have the same data you could drop the last column and then your groupby will work:

```
df = df.iloc[:, :-1].groupby('Day')
```

Comment: Two columns because each 'Day' column referes to one different symbol...so, 2 symbols, 2 columns named 'Day'. That´s why it is a little more complex.